# Access Violation painting ToolStripComboBox with WebBrowser control on XP Pro

Tags: .net, windows

I'm debugging an issue where a .NET 4.0 (WinForm, not WPF) application is crashing on Windows XP  when the user locks/unlocks the machine or when the user hits ctrl-alt-delete and then hits escape (not necessarily locking in this scenario -- but they have the option to lock, bring up task manager, etc.).  This is very reproducible.

It's related to painting a `ToolStripComboBox`.  This is generating an `AccessViolationException` in some of the `gdiplus` routines underneath the hood.

There are a few different ways I've seen it crash, but all in the same area of painting this control.  Here's one stack trace:

```
System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
at System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipFillRectangleI(HandleRef graphics, HandleRef brush, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height)
at System.Drawing.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brush brush, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height)
at System.Drawing.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brush brush, Rectangle rect)
at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripComboBox.ToolStripComboBoxControl.ToolStripComboBoxFlatComboAdapter.DrawFlatComboDropDown(ComboBox comboBox, Graphics g, Rectangle dropDownRect)
at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.FlatComboAdapter.DrawFlatCombo(ComboBox comboBox, Graphics g)
at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
...
```

Does anyone have suggestions on how to address this, or what the significant of the machine lock/unlock or ctrl-alt-delete screen is?

EDIT:

I boiled it down to a simple application pasted below, where it's pretty reproducible on XP Pro.  This is pretty vanilla - about as plain as we can get.  Everything is created/manipulated on the UI thread.

```
namespace Test
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }

    public class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser2.Navigate("http://www.cnn.com");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.toolStripContainer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripContainer();
            this.webBrowser2 = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
            this.toolStrip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip();
            this.toolStripLabel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripLabel();
            this.toolStripComboBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripComboBox();
            this.toolStripContainer1.ContentPanel.SuspendLayout();
            this.toolStripContainer1.TopToolStripPanel.SuspendLayout();
            this.toolStripContainer1.SuspendLayout();
            this.toolStrip1.SuspendLayout();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // toolStripContainer1
            // 
            this.toolStripContainer1.BottomToolStripPanelVisible = false;
            // 
            // toolStripContainer1.ContentPanel
            // 
            this.toolStripContainer1.ContentPanel.Controls.Add(this.webBrowser2);
            this.toolStripContainer1.ContentPanel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(555, 268);
            this.toolStripContainer1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.toolStripContainer1.LeftToolStripPanelVisible = false;
            this.toolStripContainer1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.toolStripContainer1.Name = "toolStripContainer1";
            this.toolStripContainer1.RightToolStripPanelVisible = false;
            this.toolStripContainer1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(555, 296);
            this.toolStripContainer1.TabIndex = 1;
            this.toolStripContainer1.Text = "toolStripContainer1";
            // 
            // toolStripContainer1.TopToolStripPanel
            // 
            this.toolStripContainer1.TopToolStripPanel.Controls.Add(this.toolStrip1);
            // 
            // webBrowser2
            // 
            this.webBrowser2.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.webBrowser2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.webBrowser2.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 20);
            this.webBrowser2.Name = "webBrowser2";
            this.webBrowser2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(555, 268);
            this.webBrowser2.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // toolStrip1
            // 
            this.toolStrip1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.None;
            this.toolStrip1.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
            this.toolStripLabel1,
            this.toolStripComboBox1});
            this.toolStrip1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 0);
            this.toolStrip1.Name = "toolStrip1";
            this.toolStrip1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(173, 28);
            this.toolStrip1.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // toolStripLabel1
            // 
            this.toolStripLabel1.Name = "toolStripLabel1";
            this.toolStripLabel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(38, 25);
            this.toolStripLabel1.Text = "blah";
            // 
            // toolStripComboBox1
            // 
            this.toolStripComboBox1.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
            this.toolStripComboBox1.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
            "a b",
            "c",
            "d",
            "e",
            "f"});
            this.toolStripComboBox1.Name = "toolStripComboBox1";
            this.toolStripComboBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(121, 28);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(555, 296);
            this.Controls.Add(this.toolStripContainer1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
            this.toolStripContainer1.ContentPanel.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.toolStripContainer1.TopToolStripPanel.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.toolStripContainer1.TopToolStripPanel.PerformLayout();
            this.toolStripContainer1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.toolStripContainer1.PerformLayout();
            this.toolStrip1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.toolStrip1.PerformLayout();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
        }
        #endregion

        private ToolStripContainer toolStripContainer1;
        private ToolStrip toolStrip1;
        private ToolStripLabel toolStripLabel1;
        private ToolStripComboBox toolStripComboBox1;
        private WebBrowser webBrowser2;
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:

I couldn't reproduce this on Windows XP Media Center edition, only XP Pro so far.

Comment: This is a problem induced by the SystemEvents class. It is firing its events on the wrong thread.

Comment: @HansPassant I pasted the source code for an application demonstrating the problem.  Everything is done on the UI thread.

Comment: Amazing bug. Is the web browser control required? It would be weird if both toolstrip and browser were required.

Comment: @usr As far as I can tell they're both required.  They being (1) a Web Browser that has been navigated and (2) a tool strip containing a ToolStripComboBox.  I'm unable to reproduce the problem if I remove the navigation call, or if I remove the combo box.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Because I've the same kind of exception, slightly different stacktrace, but I've the same problem with webBrowser+AccessViolationException+Only on xp

Comment: @J4N nope, never found a solution.  we 'think' it's related to some corporate security software that does dll injection really early in the lifetime of the process.  we couldn't reproduce on any xp images that did not have the security software.

Answer (score 1):

We've had this issue for a while now.  Same call stack, and happens when a user does the ctrl-alt-del and escape.
Scenario is a bit different in that it occurs in our WinForm app which is a mix of WinForm and WPF controls.  In the app we have a WPF UserControl hosted in an ElementHost, and when this component is in a floating window, hovering over a WinForm control that is re-drawing, and the screen is locked and unlocked, the AccessViolationException is raised and the app crashes.  I should mention that we are also using Infragistics UltraDockWorkspace.

We haven't found a solution yet, but when debugging recently using MS source, I noticed this comment at the method where the exception is thrown (in Graphics.cs in System.Drawing) :

```
         /// <devdoc>
    ///     GDI+ will return a 'generic error' with specific win32 last error codes when
    ///     a terminal server session has been closed, minimized, etc...  We don't want 
    ///     to throw when this happens, so we'll guard against this by looking at the
    ///     'last win32 error code' and checking to see if it is either 1) access denied 
    ///     or 2) proc not found and then ignore it. 
    ///
    ///     The problem is that when you lock the machine, the secure desktop is enabled and 
    ///     rendering fails which is expected (since the app doesn't have permission to draw
    ///     on the secure desktop). Not sure if there's anything you can do, short of catching
    ///     the desktop switch message and absorbing all the exceptions that get thrown while
    ///     it's the secure desktop. 
    /// </devdoc>
    private void CheckErrorStatus(int status) { 
        if (status != SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.Ok) { 
            // Generic error from GDI+ can be GenericError or Win32Error.
            if (status == SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GenericError || status == SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.Win32Error) { 
                int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                if (error == SafeNativeMethods.ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED || error == SafeNativeMethods.ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND ||
                        //here, we'll check to see if we are in a term. session...
                        (((UnsafeNativeMethods.GetSystemMetrics(NativeMethods.SM_REMOTESESSION) & 0x00000001) != 0) && (error == 0))) { 
                        return;
                    } 
                } 

            //legitimate error, throw our status exception 
            throw SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.StatusException(status);
        }
    }
```

From what I understand here, the AccessViolationException should be supressed here due to rendering during secure desktop mode, but in certain scenarios, this exception is being propagated.

Sorry I can't provide a solution, but hopefully this info is of use.